# @angular/cli didn't ask for routing or stylesheets

Tags: angular-cli, git-bash

When I create a new project on git bash in Windows with `ng new project` CLI didn't ask me for Angular routing or stylesheets. But when I try it in VScode the CLI asks me for it.

```
$which ng (git bash and bash on vscode)
../AppData/Roaming/npm/ng
```

I don't have double angular/cli version and I'm running 9.0.6 version

Comment: Do you use Git Bash in VSCode?

Comment: well yes shouldn't i?

Comment: Yes you should. I'm just asking because if you were using Powershell or Cmd, maybe the ng cli they used would be taken from elsewhere. My only suggestion is double check that everything is using the same `ng` version